# Doctrine2: discover last ID of the table?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm writing a query and i have to discover the ID of the last inserted item in a table with Doctrine.

I had to:

```
$this->getDoctrine()->getConnection()->prepare("SELECT MAX(id) FROM Commit");
```

Comment: Don't do that as you may wrong results.  Why do you need the last id?  In most cases, a flush operation will take care of setting any new id's correctly.  It will also set the id of any inserted entities so you can just use that if you really need it.  But I have yet to come across a valid use case for doctrine.

Answer (score 0):

When you flush, Doctrine will assign the entity id to your entity.
Let say your entity is:

```
class MyEntity {
  protectd $id;

  public function getId() {
     return $this->id;
  }

  public function setId($id) {
     $this->id = $id;
  }
}
```

When you do the EntityManager::flush(), the last inserted Id will be assign to the $id property. Then you just do $myEntity->getId() to get the last inserted id.

Comment: Actually that's not quite true. The Entity stays in the same state. To get the changes applied to your entity you must tell the manager to update it. Like so..  $em->refresh($myEntity);

Comment: You sure about that?  I just ran a quick test and confirmed that the id is set without a refresh.  I suppose it might behave differently in some cases but for a simple auto-inc I have never noticed a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Doctrine doesn't have any methods to do that, with flush only works if is recently inserted and only for the user who inserted that. But if you don't want to querying that table because it's big or because something else, you can make another table to store that id, and updating that every times some user adds a new element to that table. If you don't want to do that, then you have to do that you said.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by Cerad you really shouldn't retrieve your entities id by performing another query. Instead you can have the entity manager populate (update) your entity with the identifier it got on insert. An example would be..

```
$myEntity = new \Entities\MyEntity();
$myEntity->setProperty($someValue);

// Save my entity ($em = EntityManager)
$em->persist($myEntity);

// Flush my entity manager
try {
   $em->flush();
} catch (\Exception $e)
{
}

// Refresh my entity (populate the identifier)
$em->refresh($myEntity);

// Tada
echo $myEntity->getId();
```

Comment: The thing is, i'm not creating new entities or removing... I have no idea who is doing that, it's in another part of the application during another period of time. I just want to know what's the current ID.

Comment: Ah I see, then I guess what you're doing is right. Although it can be done through using DQL, rather than preparing a custom query. $q = $em->createQuery('SELECT MAX(id) FROM Commit'); $res = $q->getSingleResult(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);

Comment: Also, be aware that this value could change during execution unless your using a transaction database. Ie, you select max value, system updates new max value, you're now working with the wrong value.